# C: passing function pointer twice

Tags: c, function-pointers

I would like to write a flexible C program that allows me to do several different operations. Below is my code but it doesn’t work.

```
int result;

Void operation(void (*funcpt1)(int (*funcpt2)(int i)))
{
    (*funcpt1)(funcpt2());
}

Void sum(void (*funcpt)(void))
{
    int i;
    result = 0;
    for(i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        result += (*funcpt)(i);
    }
}

Void multiply(void (*funcpt)(void))
{
    int i;
    result = 1;
    for(i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        result *= (*funcpt)(i);
    }
}

int square(int i)
{
    return i*i;
}

int cube(int i)
{
    return i*i*i;
}

void main(void)
{
    operation(sum(square()));
    printf("%d\n",result);
    operation(sum(cube()));
    printf("%d\n",result);
    operation(multiply(square()));
    printf("%d\n",result);
    operation(multiply(cube()));
    printf("%d\n",result);
}
```

Comment: Where is the definition of `Void`?

Comment: This program does not compile. For best results, post a small self-contained sample that compiles and illustrates the problem when running it (unless you are encountering a compilation problem, in which case please state the issue)

Comment: Actually the OP assumes "it doesn'c compile" == "it doesn't work".

Comment: Use typedefs to clarify your code: typedef int (*IntToInt)(int); typedef void (*ApplyIntToInt)(IntToInt, i)

Comment: There are too many errors in your code, which indicates to me you don't understand the use of functions as arguments to other functions very well. Perhaps you can start testing with simpler use cases to gain a better understanding of the concept before you advance to the more sophisticated use cases.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int (*unary_operation)(int);
typedef int (*binary_operation)(int, int);

int add(int lhs, int rhs) {
    return lhs + rhs;
}

int multiply(int lhs, int rhs) {
    return lhs * rhs;
}

int square(int i) {
    return i*i;
}

int cube(int i) {
    return i*i*i;
}

int main() {
    unary_operation unary_op = &cube;
    printf("%d\n", unary_op(3));

    binary_operation binary_op = &add;
    printf("%d\n", binary_op(1, 2));
}
```

The output is:

```
27
3
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly assume what you are trying to achieve, then the following modified version of your code might help:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int result;

void operation(void (*funcpt1)(int (*)(int)), int (*funcpt2)(int i))
{
    (*funcpt1)(funcpt2);
}

void sum(int (*funcpt)(int))
{
    int i;
    result = 0;
    for(i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        result += (*funcpt)(i);
    }
}

void multiply(int (*funcpt)(int))
{
    int i;
    result = 1;
    for(i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        result *= (*funcpt)(i);
    }
}

int square(int i)
{
    return i*i;
}

int cube(int i)
{
    return i*i*i;
}

int main(void)
{
    operation(sum, square);
    printf("%d\n",result);
    operation(sum, cube);
    printf("%d\n",result);
    operation(multiply, square);
    printf("%d\n",result);
    operation(multiply, cube);
    printf("%d\n",result);
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this version as seen at http://ideone.com/fpUUHi, is correct, I checked it with Python and my calculator :)

Comment: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup

Comment: My fault! halex’s answer is correct. Thanks halex! This is exactly what I am looking for. My objective was to learn how to pass function pointer like that, and your answer showed me how to do it. Thanks everyone’s help.